# Lock horitzontal scroll on viewport (mobile website)

Tags: mobile, navigation, scroll, locking, viewport

i'm developing a mobile website with a vertical navigation.
It appears from the left with a simple jQuery animation, moving the main content to the right. (example: http://i49.tinypic.com/2dc7c75.jpg )
My question is:
There is any way (viewport meta, html, jquery...) to lock the horitzontal scrolling?
Now when navigation is open, user can move horitzontally. 
i need to lock this movement to force user to close navigation to see again main content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use overflow hidden so the content is pushed beyond the viewable region temporarily.